# Steps to access one of two scripts serving as a custom script for a text field residing on an Acrobat PDF form

Tags: javascript, forms, pdf, text, field

I have an interactive fillable PDF form created in Acrobat. The form essentially relies on a combo box and a hidden text field containing two scripts (serving as a custom script) one that creates a number of multidimensional arrays nested inside one large array and a 2nd script that serves to populate a number of text fields residing on the PDF form by pulling data from any one of 14 multidimensional arrays depending on the combo box selection made by the end user. So far so good regarding displaying the data associated with the combo box selection. Needless to say, the data stored inside the multidimensional arrays will need to be appended and modified in time to come given data to be added, edited, and deleted. Hence, my present task entails knowing the steps required to access the multidimensional arrays in order to append and modify the data contained therein using JS. In general, I believe I first need the ability to access the entire script to be able to separate the script that creates the array from the second one. Once done, I figure I should then be able to append/modify the data in the array via scripts. Once done, I believe all that remains is to insert/replace the entire custom script so everything is in sync. What do you think, easier said than done? I hope not.

I haven't tried anything yet. Just want to make sure I'm not spinning my wheels whereby the task is impossible to achieve.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? From what you say it sounds like it would be easiest to simply fill in the form and let the scripts work as they are.

Comment: Sorry for the convoluted post. Everything has since been resolved using custom scripts associated with a combo drop-down box and a data object that resides inside a hidden text field. In short, while I initially had serious reservations as to whether or not this was going to work, I am thrilled to report that everything works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

In regard to my initial post, I should have asked for a script to populate a drop-down combo box that resides on a PDF form using names stored inside a JS object converted to a JSON string that serves as a value in a hidden text field on the PDF form. Upon further study of the JS literal object, the required script is as follows:

```
dsFld =getField("dataSrc");// call the getField method to get the hidden text 
field used to store oVendors data object as a JSON String 
oVendors = JSON.parse(dsFld.value);// Parse the JSON string to manipulate the 
stored oVendors data object
f = getField("cbNames");// call the getField method to get the CB drop-down 
field for later use
aNames=new Array();..create a temp array
for(var key in oVendors){//script to populate the temp array from names stored 
  in oVendors data object
  aNames.push(key);
}
aNames.sort();// sort the names alphabetically
f.setItems(aNames);// assign the names from the temp array to the combo box 
field drop-down list
f.insertItemAt("Add or lookup and select a name"); // insert a string at the 
beginning of the CB drop-down list
dsFld.value=JSON.stringify(oVendors);// convert oVendors back to a JSON string

Sorry for the ambiguity in my initial post and any inconvenience to the forum.
```